# Bigfile transfer to remote server

Tags: linux, networking, scp

We are generating a bigfile (300GB) by spending 2 hours of processing. and then SCP this file to a remote server, this takes 1.5 hours.

Is there any way we can copy the file as soon as it is getting generated to the remote server ( steam the data) instead of waiting until it generated.

Or what is the best way to transfer a single large file to the remote server?   Appreciate your means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method has the big drawback of not knowing when the file is fully written to disk locally.   The command needs to be manually stopped when it is fully transferred.  You could look at the filesize of the local and remote and compare them.

Start the file creation.  When the file has been created and has data running to it you can start moving the data with a command like

```
 tail -c 500G -f /path/to/bigfile | ssh username@remote.ip "cat > /tmp/del.file"
```

There are multiple variants of this command, and other things you can do to make the output sexier, but lets look at this simple version to explain how it works.

- tail looks at the end of the file.
- -c 500G looks at the last 500 gigs of the file or part thereof, so you can see all the way to the beginning.
- -f is used to follow the file, ie continue to wait for more input and display it as it arrives.
- The second ssh part of the command opens an ssh session to the remote site, and writes the stream of data it receives from the tail command to the disk.

You can do a whole lot of nice things like this, like add | pv -s 300G between the tail and ssh parts of the command, which, assuming the file is known to be 300 gigs large, will show a progress report, and if you change the ssh command to include a -C it can compress the transfer (or you can pipe it through gz or something else, possibly uncompressing it instead of using cat at the end of the ssh command)

**Initial thoughts - Left here as other possibilities I came up with - especially if the "not knowing its complete" is a deal breaker**

There are multiple other solutions, each with their own pros and cons.  Try the following options out for size -

Depending on the data it may (or may not) be suitable to use something like DRBD (or its quiet cousin, which is better for long distance replication, [MARS](http://schoebel.github.io/mars/)).   Another variant of this solution might be to use ZFS replication.  All these work at a block device, and may or may not be suitable.

A somewhat less efficient (because it needs to do calculations of what blocks have been changed by checksum calculations) might be to replace scp with rsync.  You would run rsync multiple times.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990779/is-rsync-efficient-at-copying-files-that-grow-from-the-middle) is an overview of how this works.  RSYNC can run over the ssh protocol, and is file level, so, while a lot less efficient, it might be easier to implement.

Yet another mechanism (again depending on your usage case) might be to write the file directly to the remote system - ie mount the remote directory using NFS, SMB, or, at a push, SSHFS.   This is likely to be the most efficient, but it means you don't get to keep a copy on the local server, and disruptions to connectivity can cause bigger setbacks.  The advantage is this is easy to set up and low CPU.